# Integrating articulate storyline in asp.net web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, scorm2004, articulate-storyline

I am new to  e-learning domain and I may be using incorrect terminology.  Our coaching team has been using Articulate storyline to create interactive tutorials. Now we want to integrate these tutorials into our asp.net web site.

This is not a LMS. What I mean by integration is that is should able to play the tutorial, should able to track the progress and should able to capture the user response.  To do this I think I will need to implement a SCORM player in my asp.net web site.

Can someone point me to online resources which will help me in capturing the user response?

When I publish my project and opt for LMS and use SCORM-2004 option, it generates the package and I can see that there some js files like (lms.js and LMSAPI.js) are generated. Do I need to write my code in those js files to capture the data?

I can think of following options:

1. Use third party library like SCORM cloud
2. Read the SCORM specification guide, learn the protocol and implement
   my own SCORM player
3. User DotNetScorm open source project as a baseline and work from
   there

If anyone can guide me or point me to right direction/resources that will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

SCORM is JavaScript-based, so you will need to intercept the JavaScript calls, then use your own backend code (ajax/xmlhttprequest) to get/set the data in your database.

Claude Ostyn (who passed away a few years back) created a [SCORM test wrapper](http://ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/scorm2004testwrapwrap.htm) that mimics the SCORM API typically provided by an LMS. You can use this to provide a basic no-frills SCORM API in the browser. You'd then need to edit Ostyn's code to do something with captured data (data sent to the LMS via `API.SetValue` calls).

SCORM can get really complicated, but if you stick to the basic runtime calls (bookmark, completion status, score) you can cobble it all together in a couple of days.

Comment: Thanks @pipwerks. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes.